# Django Rest Framework create object additional data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django 2.0, I have two models **post** and **group**, in **post** there is a **ForeignKey** poiting to **group**. I have a detail view of a **group** at '*/group/name_of_group*' where I can create an instance of a **post**.
So basically, When we create the **post** the field **group** of it should be automatically set as the page's **group** (let's say group X, so we're at '*/group/X*') and we send data to : POST to /api/post/create
How to do that? 
Here's my code:
My models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)#the owner when we delete him, all his posts are deleted
    group       = models.ForeignKey(Group, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', unique=True)
```

My form:

```
class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model   = Post 
         fields  = [
              "content", 
              "group"
               ]
```

My API View to create the post:

```
class PostCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView): #/api/group/create
    serializer_class    = PostModelSerializer           
    permission_classes  = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

the ajax call when I submit the form

```
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
       method   : "POST",
       url      : '/api/post/create',
       data     : formData,//data contains our new post
       success  : function(data){
         this_.find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");//a display function for html
         attachPost(data, prepend = true);//a display function for html

       },
       error    : function(data){
         console.log("ERROR:CH0x2 while fetching after creation form submit");
         console.log("data :",data.status, data.statusText);
       }
     });
```

**N.B** an example is to set the owner of the post we override the method **perform_create** *(in PostCreateAPIView)* to set the user as the **request.user** like this

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):               # create the post
    serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
```

but I can't get the **group** name or pk in that method

///////EDIT/////////

I could change my create url from:
**/api/post/create** 
to
**/api/post/name_group/create**

Thank you

Comment: I don't realy understand what you'r trying to do, do you want that your new Post's group is set to 'create' (because you did your request on /group/create) ? Otherwise what exactly is in your "data contains our new post" ? how django is supposed to guess which group to add in the Post if you don't tell him one way or another ?

Comment: I want to create a new post and set the group automatically from the request (it contains the group in kwargs) but where can I access this request to get the group name and set it on the formData 
Thank you!

Comment: In `PostModelForm` **fields** attribute includes `group`, so the form will have select widget for group. If i understand you should omit the group from fields, right?

Answer (score 0):

I used JQuery to do that,
On document ready, I selected the item and set it's value which I managed to pass in my *serializer*, and finally I hid the item like this: (the item is a  HTML item)

the HTMl: (post-container is where I'm gonna append my posts

```
<p id="post-container" group-id     = "{{object.pk}}">

    </p>
```

the Serializer class:

```
class GroupModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model  = Group   # the model to get fields from
    fields = [      
    'id',//this is the id I get and set on the choice field (<select>)
    'moderators',
    'name',
    'description',
    'timestamp'

    ]
```

the JS:

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){ 
var selectGroup   = $('#create-post').find('select');//create-post is the id of the form html item where I put the django generated form
var postContainer = $('#post-container');
var labelGroup   = $('#create-post').find('label');
var groupId       = postContainer.attr("group-id");
selectGroup.val(groupId); selectGroup.prop('disabled',true); selectGroup.hide();labelGroup.hide()
initAjaxVariables('post-container', fetchDataUrl, postDataUrl); // init variables
initPostListDisplay(); //Fetch posts and display them
});
```

Thank you all!